# nodejs redis@4.2.0 not working as expected in rainy days

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, redis, node-redis

I have upgraded to redis 4.2.0 with the following lambda :

```
import * as redis from "redis";
export const handler = async (
        event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context, callback: APIGatewayProxyCallback
    ) => {
        try {
            console.log(`Lambda triggered with event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
            context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
            const redisClient = redis.createClient({
                socket: {
                    host: '127.0.0.1',
                    port: 6379,
                    reconnectStrategy: function (retriesAttemptedSoFar: number): number | Error {
                        if (retriesAttemptedSoFar > 3) {
                            // End reconnecting with error
                            return new Error(`Redis retry attempt=${retriesAttemptedSoFar}`);
                        }
                        console.info(` try reconnect after ${Math.min(retriesAttemptedSoFar * 10, 30)}ms`);
                        // reconnect after
                        return Math.min(retriesAttemptedSoFar * 10, 30);
                    }
                },
            });
            redisClient.on('ready', () => {
                console.log(`Got "ready" event from Redis. Connection established.`);
            });
            redisClient.on('connect', () => {
                console.log(`Got "connect" event from Redis. Stream is connected to the server`);
            });
            redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
                console.log(`Got an ERROR from Redis. Details: ${err.message}`);
            });
            await redisClient.connect();
            let serverStates : string[] = [];
            const MAX_RETRIES = 3;
            let i = 0;
            while (i < MAX_RETRIES) {
                try {
                    serverStates = await redisClient.lRange('123', 0, -1);
                } catch (e) {
                    i++;
                    const logMessage = i < MAX_RETRIES ?
                        `attempt ${i}: Failed to store message. Trying again...` :
                        `attempt ${i}: Failed to store message. All attempts failed`;
                    console.warn(logMessage);
                    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
                }
            }
            if (i >= MAX_RETRIES) {
                throw new Error('Exceeded Max Attempts to store message in Redis');
            }
            console.log(`ServerStates: ${JSON.stringify(serverStates)}`);
    
            console.log(`${JSON.stringify(event)} Lambda finished successfully`);
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: 'theResult'
            });
        } catch (e) {
            const error = e as Error;
            console.error(`Lambda execution failed. Got error: ${error.message}`);
            callback(error);
        }
    }
```

If I do not get exception from redis, all works.

1. If I do not specify **reconnectStrategy** and redis connection fail, the code trys to reconnect inifinitly.
2. If redis connection fail with **reconnectStrategy** code, lambda gets to the catch section after 3 re-connections as expected.

Comment: https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/2237
https://github.com/redis/node-redis/pull/2226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

version 4.3.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After talking privatly with @Ida on the phone, here is a summary of the error and a ***possible*** explanation of the bug (in redis library):

Summary of the problem:

1. I have error handling for everything. with logs.
2. after successful connect and before `await redisClient.lRange('123', 0, -1);` (I have "await"!!!!), I stop redis server locally and expect the reconnectStrategy to be triggered inside lRange function.
3. I do NOT turn on redis server locally.
4. ***Expected behavior***: I am expecting the reconnectStrategy to fail eventually and propagate the error to the `await redisClient.lRange('123', 0, -1);` (await !!!!).
5. ***Actual behavior***: the error is not propagated to the catch of the `await redisClient.lRange('123', 0, -1);` and just thrown to the event loop and the process ends gracefully (exit code = 0 !!!! instead of 1").